# Выполнить функцию при нажатие на кнопку

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт который проверяет в блоке наличие других похожих блоков и если добавлять дубликат, он выведет `confirm` окно.
Хочу использовать своё окно. Допустим из двух кнопок, как мне реализовать "ответку" от кнопок?

Код проверки:

```
function DuplicateCheck(value) {
  let a = true, b = '', result = true;
  $('.selected .item').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('.name').text() == value) {
      if(b == '') {
        result = confirm(value+' уже есть в списке. Добавить дубликат?');
        b = value;
        a = result;
        if(result==false) $('.add').val('');
      }
    }
  });
  return a
}
```

p.s. уверен что название темы не правильное, поправьте, если знаете как правильнее)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Придется вызывать действие через callback. Напишите функцию, которая покажет модальное окно, в нее одним из параметров передайте функцию, которую нужно выполнить при нажатии ОК. На ОК повесьте эту функцию.